# Servlet URL redirecting

Tags: jsp, servlets

In my JAVA Dynamic Web Application i am passing a value from a Payment.jsp to a servlet by action="post".
In servlet doPost() method:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws     
    ServletException, IOException {

    String cost=request.getParameter("COST_ID");
    HttpSession session=request.getSession();
    synchronized (session) {  
        session.setAttribute("payamount", cost);
    }
    request.setAttribute("cost", cost);
    request.getRequestDispatcher("makepayment.jsp").forward(request, response); 
}
```

in makepayment.jsp i get the value by using  ${cost}

my problem is when i go the the address bar and press enter the ${cost} prints nothing.

In know thats because it calls doGet() method but how can i solve ths problem?

Comment: your objective is not clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to understand the flow of a servlet application.

When you submit a form in a browser, the browser serializes the input parameters and creates a `GET`/`POST` request. It sends this request to your server and a servlet is chosen to handle it. The attributes you put in the request attributes are good for the lifecycle of that request, ie. until a response is returned. They won't be available in a second request.

In your question, you submit a `POST` request (ex. by clicking a button), the request is sent and your servlet's `doPost()` method is executed. These lines

```
request.setAttribute("cost", cost);
request.getRequestDispatcher("makepayment.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

add an attribute `cost` to the request attributes and forward to a `jsp` resource. That resource will have access to the request attributes, ex. `${cost}`, while generating the response that will eventually be returned to the client.

*my problem is when i go the the address bar and press enter the ${cost} prints nothing.*

If you go to the address bar and press enter, a new request is sent, so, without seeing your `doGet()`, the request attributes from the previous request won't exist. You need to persist them in some way, possibly with session attributes.